# WPF - need multicolored combobox

Tags: wpf, combobox, richtext

I'm trying to create a wpf combobox where certain keywords in the item text are always a different color (eg, phrase "abc" should always be blue, even if it's just a part of a longer word).  Ideally, this should apply to all templates of the combobox:  selected item, dropdown items, *and* the editing textbox as the user is typing new entries ("IsEditable" is set to true).

My initial thought is to use rich text controls for the templates of the combobox, but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to set the editing template.  Even then, I'm not sure how to proceed on enforcing keyword coloring as the user types.  Suggestions?